# PowerShell WSUS query won't use all Classifications

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate some WSUS stuff using powershell!

When I run this command:

```
Get-WSUSClassification -WSUSserver MyServer
```

The result is as expected: We have all these classifications:

```
Title              ID                                  
-----              --                                  
Applications       5c9376ab-8ce6-464a-b136-22113dd69801
Critical Updates   e6cf1350-c01b-414d-a61f-263d14d133b4
Definition Updates e0789628-ce08-4437-be74-2495b842f43b
Driver Sets        77835c8d-62a7-41f5-82ad-f28d1af1e3b1
Drivers            ebfc1fc5-71a4-4f7b-9aca-3b9a503104a0
Feature Packs      b54e7d24-7add-428f-8b75-90a396fa584f
Security Updates   0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441
Service Packs      68c5b0a3-d1a6-4553-ae49-01d3a7827828
Tools              b4832bd8-e735-4761-8daf-37f882276dab
Update Rollups     28bc880e-0592-4cbf-8f95-c79b17911d5f
Updates            cd5ffd1e-e932-4e3a-bf74-18bf0b1bbd83
Upgrades           3689bdc8-b205-4af4-8d4a-a63924c5e9d5
```

However: If I try to use any other than "All", "Critical", "Security", or "WSUS",

```
 get-wsusUpdate -approval UnApproved -Classification "Drivers" -status Needed -updateserver MyWSUS
```

I get the following error:

```
Get-WsusUpdate : Cannot bind parameter 'Classification'. Cannot convert value "Feature Packs" to type "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdateClassifications". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name Feature Packs to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: All, Critical, Security, WSUS"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Get the `WsusUpdateClassifications` object and use that. `$Drivers = Get-WSUSClassification -WSUSServer My Server | Where{$_.Title -eq 'Drivers'}` then `Get-WSUSUpdate - Approval UnApproved -Classification $Drivers -Status Needed -UpdateServer MyServer`

Comment: Unfortunately, TheMadTechnician, that didn't work. Heh, in fact, check this error out: `Get-WsusUpdate : Cannot bind parameter 'Classification'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusClassification" value of type "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusClassification" to type 
"Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdateClassifications".` Notice the SLIGHT difference.. "wsusUpdateClassification" vs. "wsusUpdateClassifications".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of poor terminology. There is WSUS Classifications, and WSUS Update Classifications, and they are different things. You already know how to see the options for the first using `Get-WsusClassification`. You can see valid options for the latter using `[enum]::GetNames(<EnumType>)` such as:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdateClassifications])
All
Critical
Security
WSUS
```

So, can we get updates classified as Feature Packs? We can, but the only way I know of to do it takes a hair more footwork. Here's how I'd do it:

```
$WSUS = Get-WsusServer
$FPClass = $WSUS.GetUpdateClassifications()|Where{$_.Title -eq 'Feature Packs'}
$FPClass.GetUpdates()
```

Now, you do know the GUID for the classification you want, so you can shorten that if you want using the GUID:

```
$WSUS.GetUpdateClassification('b54e7d24-7add-428f-8b75-90a396fa584f').GetUpdates()
```

That will get you all of the Feature Pack updates. From there you can filter out updates based on if they are superseded or not needed.

Personally I find the objects themselves much more useful than the cmdlets for WSUS, such as `$WSUS` above getting update classifications from which you can get the updates for that classification.

Comment: ** SOLVED **. Indeed.. it would seem that the object Methods & Properties are where it's at. Coming from a more traditional programming background (Think PASCAL/COBOL), OO stuff is .. always going to be "New" to me even when it's old (Like it is now) :D).